# Code Blocks and catkin Indigo?

Tags: ros, catkin, ide, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to follow the codeblocks instruction in wiki.ros.org/IDEs but when I try

- rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags PackageName
- rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=lflags PackageName

with the beginner_tutorials package, or something fancier like rviz, I just get a blank line as a result.

How can I use codeblocks to build a catkin package?

Using Indigo Igloo, ubuntu 14.04 and CodeBlocks 13.12.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190307/code-blocks-and-catkin-indigo?/) by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to integrate with CodeBlocks is convered on the [IDE wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0